# How to pull the rhs out of an equality in coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

If I have the following:

```
H : some complicated expression = some other complicated expression
```

and I want to grab

```
u := some other complicated expression
```

without hardcoding it into my proof (i.e., using `pose`)

Is there a clean way to do this in LTac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure there are other ltac ways to do it, in my case I prefer to use SSReflect's contextual pattern language to do it. (You'll need to install the plugin or use Coq >= 8.7 which includes SSReflect):

```
(* ce_i = complicated expression i *)
Lemma example T (ce_1 ce_2 : T) (H : ce_1 = ce_2) : False.
set u := (X in _ = X) in H.
```

resulting goal:

```
  T : Type
  ce_1, ce_2 : T
  u := ce_2 : T
  H : ce_1 = u
  ============================
  False
```

Usually you can refine the pattern more and more until you get a pretty stable match.

Note that this happens to be the first example of the section 8.3 "Contextual patterns" in the SSReflect manual.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another version, which uses Ltac and its ability to pattern-match on types of terms:

```
Tactic Notation "assign" "rhs" "of" ident(H) "to" ident(u) "in" ident(H') :=
  match type of H with _ = ?rhs => set (u := rhs) in H' end.

Tactic Notation "assign" "rhs" "of" ident(H) "to" ident(u) "in" "*" :=
  match type of H with _ = ?rhs => set (u := rhs) in * end.
```

We can create more variants of the above (see e.g. [here](https://coq.inria.fr/cocorico/Folding%20tactics)). Here is how to use it:

```
Lemma example {T} (ce1 ce2 ce3 : T) (H1 : ce1 = ce2) (H2 : ce2 = ce3) : ce1 = ce3.
Proof.
  assign rhs of H1 to u in *.
```

Proof state:

```
  u := ce2 : T
  H1 : ce1 = u
  H2 : u = ce3
  ============================
  ce1 = ce3
```

One more time:

```
  Undo.
  assign rhs of H1 to u in H1.
```

Proof state:

```
  u := ce2 : T
  H1 : ce1 = u
  H2 : ce2 = ce3
  ============================
  ce1 = ce3
```